# Promise scope variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having a problem in my controller with a promise. Basically I'm trying to create a if statement based on a response that I receive from my promise to the `productData`. The problem is that the variable `productData` exists inside the promise but after it doesn't -- it gets null. Is it because of the scope?

Here is my code:

```
var productData = null;

ProductService
  .queryByGroup(selectedGroup.id)
  .then(function(response) {
    productData = response.data;
  });

if (productData.hasOwnProperty('conditions') == false) {
  // Send a request to the server asking for the medicine ids of the selected group
  Meds
    .getAllProductsById(selectedGroup.id)
    .then(function(response) {

      //SOME CODE logic

    }, function(response) {
      $log.debug('Unable to load data');
      $log.debug(response.debug);
    });
} else {
  console.log("call modal");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't properly formatted but my guess is that your `if` statement is being executed in **parallel** to the async `$resource` call. Your promise has not been settled yet, therefore no data reside in `productData` which is causing the error.

The fix is to move everything depending on `productData` inside the promise callback so when it is resolved, it will be populated. like so:

```
var productData = null;
ProductService
  .queryByGroup(selectedGroup.id)
  .then(function(response) {
    productData = response.data;
    if (!productData.conditions) {
      // Send a request to the server asking for the medicine ids of the selected group
      Meds
        .getAllProductsById(selectedGroup.id)
        .then(function(response) {

          //SOME CODE logic

        }, function(response) {
          $log.debug('Unable to load data');
          $log.debug(response.debug);
        });

    } else {

      console.log("call modal");

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need handle **productData** after get response. Put your if condition inside promise function

```
 ProductService
    .queryByGroup(selectedGroup.id)
    .then(function (response){
        productData = response.data;

        if(productData.hasOwnProperty('conditions') == false){
            // Send a request to the server asking for the medicine ids of the selected group
            Meds
                .getAllProductsById(selectedGroup.id)
                .then(function (response) {

                    //SOME CODE logic

                }, function (response) {
                    $log.debug('Unable to load data');
                    $log.debug(response.debug);
                });

        }else{

            console.log("call modal");

        }
    });
```